# Promtail to Loki with Labels

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I am using a pattern to add tags to different log fields of my nginx ingress. Here is the query I use in Loki + referer field to look only the domian request.

```
{app="nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller",namespace="ingress"}
| pattern `<remote_addr> - - [<time_local>] "<method> <request> HTTP/<http_version>" <status> <body_bytes_sent> "<referer>" "<user_agent>" <request_time> <_> <_> <_> <status_ingress> [<resource_name>] <_> <_> <_> <log_id>`
```

[image]

I am trying my best to add this pattern to Promtail, so that the tags are default and I can do the searches without adding the pattern.

Try adding this **promtail-config.yaml**:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0
positions:
  filename: /var/lib/promtail/positions.yaml
clients:
  - url: http://loki-stack.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/push
scrape_configs:
- job_name: nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      app: nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller
      env: production
      host: ruan-prod-nginx
      __path__: /var/log/nginx/*.log
  pipeline_stages:
  - match:
      selector: '{app="nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller"}'
      stages:
      - regex:
          # logline example: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2020:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /?foo=bar HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "http://example.com/lekkebot.html" "curl/7.58.0"
          expression: '^(?P<host>[\w\.]+) - (?P<user>[^ ]*) \[(?P<timestamp>.*)\] "(?P<method>[^ ]*) (?P<request_url>[^ ]*) (?P<request_http_protocol>[^ ]*)" (?P<status>[\d]+) (?P<bytes_out>[\d]+) "(?P<http_referer>[^"]*)" "(?P<user_agent>[^"]*)"?'
      - labels:
          host:
          method:
          request_url:
          status:
          user_agent:
```

Then update my promtail config, with this command and regenerate de POD's.

```
helm upgrade loki-stack grafana/loki-stack -n monitoring --set promtail.config.promtailYaml="$(cat promtail-config.yaml)"

kubectl delete pods -n monitoring -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=loki-stack,app.kubernetes.io/name=promtail
```

I am using a Vanilla K8S Cluster with microk8s. Here the namespace, app & job.

[image]

I leave the logs of the ingress Pod's

[image]

Buy i still recive without levels.

[image]

Thanks for your help and take time to read! If you have any suggestion, lets me know!

Comment: You *should not* do this. Please read official stance of labels [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/bp-labels/) and [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/#cardinality).

Comment: @markalex you tell me that is a bad practice?

Comment: Yes. With things like `bytes_out` and `user_agent` you'll blow up cardinality of your records.

Comment: Thank you. You recommend me to build dashboards using the patterns in the query. Make in the same query the Split of the side and give it the labels. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. It's not the most elegant solution, as you'll need to repeat your queries, but this is most efficient in terms of Loki storage/performance.

Comment: Gracias @markalex. Just for knowladge. If i want be able to measure the Get's in the last hour.

sum(count_over_time({app="nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller", namespace="ingress"} 
|  pattern `<remote_addr> - - [<time_local>] "<method> <request> HTTP/<http_version>" <status> <body_bytes_sent> "<referer>" "<user_agent>" <request_time> <_> <_> <_> <status_ingress> [<resource_name>] <_> <_> <_> <log_id>` | method="GET" | referer="https://mi-dominio.xxx.com" [1h]))

Should the consultation be like this? I can't seem to get it to work.  Thanks for your advices!

Comment: On the first glance, I don't see any problems with this. I checked your pattern on play.grafana.com, it seems to work (can't share, link is too long for SO comments). Double check output of your pattern command: are all labels parsed as expected?

Comment: @markalex you are right. Thanks for your help. Its a new world LogQL. I am going to play with timestamp. Have you got some link with good examples?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255546/discussion-between-safernandez666-and-markalex).